# Android - Errors when trying to change activities

Tags: java, android

For some reason this came up when trying to switch activities. I've had no problem running the same kind of code with other activities in this project. I'll post the code and see if anyone can figure it out ;(

I can't get my error to format right in this, so here's the error log
http://textuploader.com/oe6g

Here's my different activities.

The Problem occurs when I click on the button in my New Game Activity Layout, and that button runs the confirm(View view)

NewGameActivity.java

```
public class NewGameActivity extends Activity {
EditText title;
TextView team1, team2;
SqliteHelper db;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_newgame);
    //ListViews
    team1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    team2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    db = new SqliteHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
    populateListViews();
    registerClickCallback();
}

/*
 * 
 * Database Functions
 * 
 */





/*
 * 
 * ListView Stuff
 * 
 */
private void populateListViews() {
    // THIS HERE WILL POPULATE BOTH TEAM LIST VIEWS
    //Create list of items
    Cursor cursor = db.getTeams();

    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() != 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

            values.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Team_Names")));

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }       
    //Build Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> t1adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,                   // Context
            R.layout.teamlistviews,     // Layout to use
            values);                // Items to be displayed
    ArrayAdapter<String> t2adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,                   // Context
            R.layout.teamlistviews,     // Layout to use
            values);        
    //Configure the List View
    ListView t1list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    t1list.setAdapter(t1adapter);
    ListView t2list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    t2list.setAdapter(t2adapter);
}
private void registerClickCallback() {
    //This uses the List View and adds a listener to check for clicks/taps on different
    //list view items. It will then display a message telling you which one you have selected.
    ListView t1list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ListView t2list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    t1list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                int position, long id) {
            //team 1
                TextView textView = (TextView) viewClicked;

                //Changing team name
                TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                String team1 = textView.getText().toString();
                t1.setText(team1);
                //Toast message
                String message = "You Selected " + textView.getText().toString() + " for Team 1";
                Toast.makeText(NewGameActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
    t2list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                int position, long id) {
            //team 2
                TextView textView = (TextView) viewClicked;
                //Changing Team name
                TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                String team2 = textView.getText().toString();
                t2.setText(team2);
                //Toast message
                String message = "You Selected " + textView.getText().toString() + " for Team 2";
                Toast.makeText(NewGameActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
}
public void confirm(View view) {
    String t1, t2, gTitle;
    t1 = team1.toString();
    t2 = team2.toString();
    gTitle = title.toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CourtActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("TEAM1", t1);
    intent.putExtra("TEAM2", t2);
    intent.putExtra("GAME_TITLE", gTitle);
    startActivity(intent);

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.new_game, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

CourtActivity.java

```
package com.example.statapalpha;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.ArrayList;

// Court Screen
public class CourtActivity extends Activity implements OnMenuItemClickListener{

// Opens database
SqliteHelper db;

ArrayList<String> homePlayersIn = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> awayPlayersIn = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> homePlayersBench = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> awayPlayersBench = new ArrayList<String>();

String team1, team2, team1n, team2n;
String player = "0"; // Player number for current play
String action = ""; // Action text for current play
position position = new position(); // Position for current play
int playNumber = 0;
private PopupMenu popupMenu;
boolean isHome = false;
int playerButton = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_court);
    db = new SqliteHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
    //Get Team 1 and 2 and Game Title
    convertStrings();
    // Gets players
    getPlayers();
}
public void convertStrings() {
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    team1n = mIntent.getStringExtra("TEAM1");
    team2n = mIntent.getStringExtra("TEAM2");
}
// Populates arrays with player numbers
void getPlayers() {
    homePlayersBench.add("12");
    homePlayersBench.add("10");
    homePlayersBench.add("32");
    homePlayersBench.add("16");
    homePlayersBench.add("13");
    homePlayersBench.add("19");

    homePlayersIn.add("13");
    homePlayersIn.add("14");
    homePlayersIn.add("15");
    homePlayersIn.add("16");
    homePlayersIn.add("17");

    awayPlayersBench.add("21");
    awayPlayersBench.add("22");
    awayPlayersBench.add("23");
    awayPlayersBench.add("24");
    awayPlayersBench.add("25");
    awayPlayersBench.add("26");

    awayPlayersIn.add("31");
    awayPlayersIn.add("32");
    awayPlayersIn.add("33");
    awayPlayersIn.add("34");
    awayPlayersIn.add("35");
}

// Stores x and y coordinate
public class position {
    public int x;
    public int y;
}

// Sets current player when a player button is clicked
public void setPlayer(View v) {
    Button b = (Button)v;
    player = b.getText().toString();
    playerButton = b.getId();
    switch(b.getId()) {
    case R.id.p1: 
    case R.id.p2:
    case R.id.p3:
    case R.id.p4:
    case R.id.p5: isHome = true; break;
    default: isHome = false;
            break;
    }
}

// Sets string Action to whatever action the user taps
// then records play to database.
public void setAction(View v) {
    Button b = (Button)v;
    String toastAction = "";
    String message = "";
    String team = "";

    switch(b.getId()) {
    case R.id.fgMade: action = "F" + goal(position) + "H"; toastAction = "made " + goal(position) + " point shot";
    break;
    case R.id.fgMissed: action = "F" + goal(position) + "M"; toastAction = "missed " + goal(position) + " point shot";
    break;
    case R.id.ftMade: action = "FTH"; toastAction = "made freethrow";
    break;
    case R.id.ftMissed: action = "FTM"; toastAction = "missed freethrow";
    break;
    case R.id.rebound: action = "RB"; toastAction = "rebound";
    break;
    case R.id.assist: action = "AST"; toastAction = "assist";
    break;
    case R.id.block: action = "BL"; toastAction = "block";
    break;
    case R.id.steal: action = "STL"; toastAction = "steal";
    break;
    case R.id.turnover: action = "TO"; toastAction = "turnover";
    break;
    case R.id.sub: action = "SUB"; toastAction = "substitution";
    break;
    case R.id.foul: action = "FC"; toastAction = "commited foul";
    break;
    case R.id.undoPlay: undoPlay(v);
    break;
    }

    if (action == "SUB") {
        popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this.getBaseContext(), v);
        Menu menu = popupMenu.getMenu();

        if (isHome == true) {
            for (String number : homePlayersBench) {
                menu.add(number);
            }
        }
        else {
            for (String number : awayPlayersBench) {
                    menu.add(number);
                }
        }

        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        popupMenu.show();

        return;
    }
    else {
        message = "Player " + player + " " + toastAction + " at ("  + Integer.toString(position.x) + ", " + Integer.toString(position.y) + ")";
    }

    if (isHome == true)
        team = team1;
    else
        team = team2;

    playNumber++;
    db.recordPlay(Integer.parseInt(player), team, action, position, playNumber);
    Toast.makeText(CourtActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    refreshPlayers();
}


// Gets tap position and saves it to 'position'
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        position.x = (int)event.getX(0);
        position.y = (int)event.getY(0);
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

int goal(position position) {
    int points=3;

    if ((Math.sqrt(Math.pow((position.x - 1082), 2) + Math.pow((position.y - 453), 2)) < 270) || (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((position.x - 193), 2) + Math.pow((position.y - 453), 2)) < 270)) points = 2;

    return points;
}


public void undoPlay(View v) {

    db.undoPlay(Integer.toString(playNumber));
}



@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(playerButton);
    button.setText(item.getTitle());
    refreshPlayers();
    return false;
}
}
```

activity_court.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg2court"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/editPlays"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:onClick="editPlays"
    android:text="@string/edit_plays"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/undoPlay"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editPlays"
    android:onClick="undoPlay"
    android:text="@string/undo" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ftMissed"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="setAction"
    android:text="@string/miss" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ftMade"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ftMissed"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="setAction"
    android:text="@string/made" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/fgMade"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/fgMissed"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="setAction"
    android:text="@string/made" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/fgMissed"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ftMade"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
    android:onClick="setAction"
    android:text="@string/miss" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fgText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/fgMade"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/playerStats"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="@string/field_goal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="38sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/playerStats"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/undoPlay"
    android:onClick="redoPlay"
    android:text="@string/playerStats" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ftText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ftMade"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fgText"
    android1:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ftMade"
    android:text="@string/free_throw"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="34sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/foul"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ftMade"
    android:onClick="setAction"
    android:color= "#FF0079FF"
    android:text="@string/foul" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/steal"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/turnover"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:onClick="setAction"
    android:text="@string/steal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/block"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/steal"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:onClick="setAction"
    android:text="@string/block" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/assist"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/block"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:onClick="setAction"
    android:text="@string/assist" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/rebound"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/assist"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:onClick="setAction"
    android:text="@string/rebound" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/p1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rebound"
    android:onClick="setPlayer"
    android:text="@string/p1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/p2"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/p1"
    android:onClick="setPlayer"
    android:text="@string/p2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/p3"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/p2"
    android:onClick="setPlayer"
    android:text="@string/p3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/p4"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/p3"
    android:onClick="setPlayer"
    android:text="@string/p4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/p5"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/p4"
    android:onClick="setPlayer"
    android:text="@string/p5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/p10"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editPlays"
    android:onClick="setPlayer"
    android:text="@string/p10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/p9"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/p10"
    android:onClick="setPlayer"
    android:text="@string/p9" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/p8"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/p9"
    android:onClick="setPlayer"
    android:text="@string/p8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/p7"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/p8"
    android:onClick="setPlayer"
    android:text="@string/p7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/p6"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/p7"
    android:onClick="setPlayer"
    android:text="@string/p6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sub"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/foul"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/p1"
    android:onClick="setAction"
    android:text="@string/sub" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/turnover"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/sub"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/p1"
    android:onClick="setAction"
    android:text="@string/turnover" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/points"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/court"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rebound"
    android:text="@string/points"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fouls"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/undoPlay"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/p1"
    android:text="@string/fouls"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p1p"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/points"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p1"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p1p"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p1f"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fouls"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p1"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p1f"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p2p"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/points"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p2"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p2p"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p2f"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fouls"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p2"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p2f"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p3p"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/points"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p3"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p3p"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p3f"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fouls"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p3"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p3f"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p4p"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/points"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p4"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p4p"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p4f"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fouls"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p4"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p4f"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p5p"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/points"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p5"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p5p"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p5f"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fouls"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p5"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p5f"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p6p"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/points"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p6"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p6p"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p6f"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fouls"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p6"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p6f"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p7p"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/points"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p7"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p7p"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p7f"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fouls"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p7"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p7f"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p8p"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/points"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p8"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p8p"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p8f"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fouls"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p8"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p8f"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p9p"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/points"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p9"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p9p"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p9f"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fouls"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p9"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p9f"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p10p"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/points"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p10"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p10p"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p10f"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fouls"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p10"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:text="@string/p10f"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/court"
    android:layout_width="900dp"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/p10"
    android:contentDescription="@string/undo"
    android:src="@drawable/court" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I mean it tells me the error occurs in the onCreate of the CourtActivity, however I can't see anything that's wrong. This is part of my school project, I'm only concerned with the things that are causing me errors currently, not too worried about anything else.

Note:This is a group project. The courtactivity screen is the only one I've not had a part in making, so I'm not sure exactly what went into it. However now I'm trying to put everything together and running into this.

Anything helps! Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your layout file (R.layout.activity_court)?

Comment: I've posted it. Thanks for such a quick response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is happening while attempting to load an image specified on the Layout file, as reported by the following part of the log:

```
...: Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
...: E/AndroidRuntime(2137):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
...: E/AndroidRuntime(2137):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
```

I bet if you remove the line `android:background="@drawable/bg2court"` from the root container (RelativeLayout) in the file activity_court.xml the error will be gone.
If that is the case I would suggest you to try a smaller (lower resolution) version of that image.
While looking for a replacement, keep an eye on the heap memory allocation messages on logcat so you will know how much progress you are making.

Loading high resolution images on Android is usually a tricky process because of the following reasons:

1. Bitmap files loaded in memory have to be decompressed so they can be rendered, making them a lot larger then their original .JPG and .PNG files. To calculate how many bytes of memory will be allocated to load a given image, just follow this simple formula: width (*pixels*) x height (*pixels*) x number bytes per pixel (3 for 24 bit images). Example: a bitmap with the size of 2048x2048 pixels takes exactly 12mb of memory;
2. Bitmaps are loaded into the heap space which happens to be a pretty small portion of memory given by the OS to your app when it starts. The size of the heap space usually ranges from 16 to 64mb depending on the device.

Finally, I would suggest one of the following approaches:

1. Replace the large background image by a lower resolution version that can be scaled up to fill the background space (at the cost of quality of corse);
2. Load bitmaps programmatically. There are BitmapFactory methods that can downsample images on the fly, during the load process. More on this [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html);
3. Use a 3rd party library to do it for you. [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) is an excelent choice.

Comment: Oh okay! Thank you so much. So do you think that it would work if we put it in on the tablet? We're only receiving the errors when trying to run it in our emulator. The Galaxy tablet we have definitely runs a lot faster

Comment: More speed wont help you with this issue. The problem is that images allocate space from the heap space that is given to your app. The size of that heap is unfortunately pretty small on most Android devices (from 16 to 64mb depending on several factors but mostly on the total amount of physical memory in the device). One thing you could do instead of asking the layout manager to try loading the entire large image in memory is to load the image programmatically using BitmapFactory. I'll add more info to my post to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from inflating the layout.  It's an OutOfMemoryError.  Do you have some really huge bitmap or more likely a circular dependency?  Can you upload the xml file R.layout.activity_court?

Comment: Alright I added that into the original post. I hit character limit so i removed the refreshPlayers() from courtactivity.java which shouldn't make a difference for the error.
Thank you for a quick response btw!

One other thing, I can run the courtactivity fine when I launch it from  our home screen. For some reason launching it from the NewGameActivity screen causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error no long ago but got some help from the guys in here

here is what I did

if your background / image don't need transpart stuff or like keep in JPG format as it will be smaller. this should sort your Out of Memory issue temp. but when you have more image coming up you will still have problem (Out of Memory) coming up again

hope this can help you for the time been